# StaticResource vs StaticResourceExtension syntax

Tags: wpf, xaml, staticresource, markup-extensions

What's the difference between.

```
<TextBox Text="{local:BindingResourceExtension MyBinding}" >
    <TextBox.Style>
        <StaticResourceExtension  ResourceKey="style" />
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

and

```
<TextBox Text="{local:BindingResourceExtension MyBinding}" Style="{StaticResource style}"/>
```

Which should be preferred in XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. The curly brace syntax is designed specifically so you can use markup extensions within attribute values without having to resort to specifying the properties as child elements like in the first example. So, naturally, the curly brace syntax is preferred in those situations.

Comment: I do not follow what you mean by your second sentence?

Comment: Put it this way: would you rather write it the first way or the second way? If you'd rather write it the first way, no one can stop you. But I'd rather write it the second way. And I think the vast majority of XAML authors would agree. It's so much cleaner and simpler.

Comment: If I replace StaticResource with StaticResourceExtension in second code block, it still works. So I guess it's similer case like string= String. Do you know why it is designed this way?

Comment: To make life easier?

Comment: @EmperorAiman ok, may be for us it becomes easier that way, but wouldn't it had put a little bit more programming/ performance hit to resolve x into xExtension to actually resolve the original class at run time?

Comment: I don't know how it's resolved, but I guess it's a compile time feature. Just like Attributes in .NET. You don't have to put Attribute at the end, but it still compiles

Comment: @EmperorAiman there are a lot of design decision in WPF that i can't understand , why they were taken? I wish there is some sort of AI built by Microsoft that could answer all that.... ;) but thanks for your help... :)